# Android DDMS Error: AMI_IsWindowSearch()

Tags: android, debugging, ddms

I have written an android app that generates a strange exception on the LG-Phone I have just started testing on. In DDMS the tag is "ISP_LOG_MW_DEBUG" and the text is "AMI_IsWindowSearch()." It is generated about 10 times per second while the app is running. It doesn't seem to interfere with the program itself, but I would rather not have this error. but I can not find any information on this on the web.

If a click the home button (the app continues running in the background) and start the app again (new UI, with the old services) the amount of these messages increases each time. So it is reasonable to assume that they are generated by something in the UI.

Has anybody experienced this error or has any idea how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Real devices can sometimes make a lot of noise.  Sometimes the vendors just leave a lot of debugging turned on.  If your app is not crashing, or showing performance issues, I would say it's safe to ignore.

Also, try with another device, or try with the emulator.  If you don't see those errors with another device or the emulator, I think it's safe to say the vendor developers of the the LG device are just lazy and didn't turn off all their debugging like a good developer should.  :D

db